# Is C++ suitable for writing backtests

Tags: backtesting

I'm looking for a library like BackTrader or platform that is written in C++ for backtesting.

Is C++ a good choice to write a backtester and are any available?

Comment: If you are backtesting on tick data and do not have a q/kdb framework, C++ is perhaps the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a Backtester in any language you want and quite a few people did so in C++ and made the source code available:

https://github.com/topics/backtesting?l=c%2B%2B

A reason to perform backtests with code written in C++ is that it can achieve very good performance.